# Disable SpringSecurity's SavedRequest storing logic

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We are using Spring Security for managing authentication.  The issue we are seeing is that when a user's session is timed out between bringing up a GET form and hitting the save button that does a POST, they are sent to the login page but spring is saving the original post information in the session.

Our app does not bring them back to the original URL after login, but instead sends them back to a common starting page.  This works fine, but when the user happens to return to the page they had originally tried to POST to (the form GET and POST are the same URLs) Spring tries to resubmit the POST automatically which is not what we want.

Is there a way to completely disable the SavedRequest storing logic in Spring?

Comment: If the session has timed out, where is the saved request coming from?

Comment: Spring appears to be saving the pre-timeout post request somewhere that the new? session still gets it.  It appears to be accessed by the AbstractProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess [this jira](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1408) issue of spring security describes your problem and how to handle this.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't able to find that jira issue.  It looks like the config I need to add is:

   <bean id="exceptionTranslator" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter"><property name="requestCache"><bean id="nullRequestCache" class="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.NullRequestCache"/></property></bean>

Comment: Is there a similar configuration for spring security 2.0.5?  ExceptionTranslationFilter does not have a requestCache

Answer (score 2):

Based on Nathan's comment on [Raghuram's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4859507/109351), with namespaced XML it's something like this:

```
<security:http>
    <security:request-cache ref="nullRequestCache" />
    <!-- ... -->
</security:http>

<bean id="nullRequestCache" class="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.NullRequestCache" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios:
1) If you want that after relogin, user should always get forwarded to the default target URL instead of the orginal requested URL then put always-use-default-target="true" in your security.xml like

```
<http auto-config="true"> 
.....
<form-login login-page="/login" always-use-default-target="true" default-target-url="/xyz" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" login-processing-url="/j_security_check"/>
</http>
```

1) If you want that on session timeout after relogin, user should forward to the orginal requested URL but you do not want to resubmit the form then put session-fixation-protection="newSession" in your security.xml like

```
<http auto-config="true">
<session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession"/> 
.....
</http>
```

Please put session-management tag as first line in http configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the session-fixation-protection="newSession" attribute on  (2.0) or  (3.0) will also resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

With Spring 4.2.5 I ran into this too.

My case was almost identical: display GET form, wait for session timeout, then POST the form. In my app after re-authentication a start page is displayed. However, if the user then navigates to this GET form, and POSTs it, then the previous POST parameters are remembered and **concatenated** to the current request, resulting in **comma separated values** in the @RequestParam variables.

I dumped the session in my authentication controller and indeed I saw a "SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST" named key.

The spring documentation says that by default a "SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler" is used for retrieving the saved request data from the session and apply it to the request.

I tried to use a do-nothing successHandler but couldn't make it work.

I also tried applying

http.sessionManagement().sessionFixation().newSession();

to the security config but that didn't help.

However

http.requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache());

solved the issue.