# How to enable Spring Security POST redirect after log in with CSRF?

Tags: java, spring, redirect, spring-security, csrf

I'm using Spring Security 3.2 with CSRF. My configuration includes this:

```
  <csrf />
  <form-login default-target-url="/defaultPage"/>
```

When the user does a POST form submit (with a CSRF token) that requires authentication, he is redirected to the log in page. Afterwards, instead of submitting the request, the user is redirected to the `defaultPage` by Spring Security.

I suspect the issue is that the CSRF token gets reset during log in.

How can I get such a POST redirect after log in working?

**Update**: I tried to create a custom `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` to redirect to the original POST request. However, I saw that the original request wasn't even being saved in the `requestCache`.

Comment: I would love to hear an answer on this. Either an explanation of how to achieve it with Spring Security, or possibly an explanation that it is inherently unsafe and therefore shouldn't/can't be done with Spring Security.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that when CSRF protection is enabled, Spring Security only puts your original request in the `requestCache` if the request used the `GET` method. In order to have it cache `POST` requests as well, I created a custom `requestCache`.

I'm not 100% convinced that doing so doesn't weaken the CSRF protection somehow, but it seems safe in my mind.

Add request cache bean to the XML configuration:

```
<bean id="requestCache" class="a.b.c.AlwaysSaveRequestCache" />

<http>
   <csrf />
   <request-cache ref="requestCache" />
</http>
```

Implement the custom request cache, by extending and borrowing code from `HttpSessionRequestCache`:

```
public class AlwaysSaveRequestCache extends HttpSessionRequestCache
{
   @Override
   public void saveRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   {
      final String SAVED_REQUEST = "SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST";
      DefaultSavedRequest savedRequest = new DefaultSavedRequest(request, new PortResolverImpl());
      request.getSession().setAttribute(SAVED_REQUEST, savedRequest);
      logger.debug("DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: " + savedRequest);
   }
}
```

Your `POST` requests should now be cached and re-sent after being interrupted by the login form.

Comment: Note that you may not always want to save a POST to a request cache because it might lead to problems described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854480/disable-springsecuritys-savedrequest-storing-logic. I'm looking into using a variation of this "AlwaysSaveRequestCache" that only allows a whitelist of POST request URLs (in addition to the default request matcher behaviour) to be saved.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple.Don't pass CSRF token in the form of hidden it wont work pass the `CSRF token` directly as `query params` to the `URL` like below

```
<c:url value="/jobseeker/resume/uploadJobSeekerResume1?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" var="uploadResumeURL"/>
 <form:form action="${uploadResumeURL}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input id="file" name="file" type="file" />
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" >
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>&nbsp;Save
                            </button>

                        </div>
                        </form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because HttpSessionRequestCache and DefaultSavedRequest are not designed to work with "multipart/form-data". Multipart request is treated as regular request and all form data is lost. The request restored from SavedRequest will contain only the URL and method.

Answer (score -1):

I may not understand something... but cant you just remove default-target-url from your configuration?

Comment: If you don't specify a target url, Spring Security redirects to the root of the domain "/" instead of submitting the previous request. This issue happens when enabling/using CSRF protection. It does not happen for GET requests (without CSRF tokens).