# How to get the form data with POST submission from the previous URL after login with CSRF in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying redirect to the previous URL with POST form submission after successful login for that i configured below bean i am able to redirect with POST submission but here i am trying to upload a file but i am unable to get the multipart object after login i.e., i am getting file object as null.Please help me to achieve this thanks in advance. Here is my bean and XML configuration.
`spring-security.xml`

```
<http>
<csrf />
<request-cache ref="requestCache"  />
</http>
<beans:bean id="requestCache" class="com.web.listeners.Test" />
```

`Test.java`

```
public class Test extends HttpSessionRequestCache {
       @Override
       public void saveRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
       response)
       {
          final String SAVED_REQUEST = "SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST";
          DefaultSavedRequest savedRequest = new DefaultSavedRequest(request, 
          new PortResolverImpl());
          request.getSession().setAttribute(SAVED_REQUEST, savedRequest);

       }
}
```

`test.jsp`

```
<c:url value="/file/uploadFile?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" var="uploadFileURL"/>
                    <form:form action="${uploadFileURL}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="multiPartVo">
                    <input id="file" name="file" type="file" />
                    <button type="submit" value="SAVE" ></button>
                    </form:form>
```

Comment: Don't know if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958224/how-to-enable-spring-security-post-redirect-after-log-in-with-csrf/43866179

Comment: @KarlNicholas thanks for your suggestion but same code they also wrote it can't solve my problem

Comment: Here i am able to redirect to the before login url after login but i am unable to get the form data i.e., multipart file data null value is coming indeed.

Comment: @KarlNicholas Here it is redirecting to the previous URL  but multipart file data is coming as NULL indeed.