# Best way to redirect POST after login with Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redirect, authentication

Learning Spring Boot. I was able to redirect GET requests after login but cannot figure out how to redirect POSTs?

For get requests I propagated redirectTo url and then accessed it via referer.

e.x. `/login?redirectTo=/users/18`

Sample below

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/entries/**", "/search", "/signup").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/adminpanel/**")
        .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
        .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler())
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/clearConnection")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();

    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
  }


  public AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler()  {
    return (request, response, authentication) ->
    {
      String referer = request.getHeader("referer");
      List<org.apache.http.NameValuePair> params = null;
      String redirectUrl;

      try {
        params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(referer), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        //TODO: throw exception properly
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      if (!params.isEmpty()) {
        org.apache.http.NameValuePair nameValuePair = params.get(0);
        redirectUrl = nameValuePair.getValue();
        response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
      }else{
        response.sendRedirect("/");
      }

    };
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to redo the POST action automatically after the user logs in? Disabling CSRF doesn't sound like a good idea. With CSRF enabled 
I don't think there is a simple way to achieve exactly what you need. I think you'll need to provide a RequestCache that saves the POST request and after the user logs in you'll need to "re-apply" it. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958224/how-to-enable-spring-security-post-redirect-after-log-in-with-csrf). Also see RequestCacheConfigurer.createDefaultSavedRequestMatcher().