# login and checkout user redirecting to home page how to redirect to cart page in sap hybris

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice, impex

here in my case. in this method

```java
onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
     final RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
     final SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
```

i am getting savedRequest  is NULL how to get my expected result

Comment: You might want to include a little more detail ...

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958224/how-to-enable-spring-security-post-redirect-after-log-in-with-csrf/43844636 . It guides you on how to use saved cache in spring security to redirect after successful login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `CheckoutLoginController.java`, 
add `private static final String REFERER = "referer";`

In `doCheckoutLogin` method, add `request.getSession().setAttribute("redirectTargetUrl", request.getHeader(REFERER));`

After this, the request will be added to the session.